# Again Q_OBJECT linker error

Tags: c++, macos, qt

As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067734/qt-link-error-related-to-q-object), I get an error after adding `Q_OBJECT` into my class `QServer`:

```
class QServer : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

...
```

The errors i get are the following:

> Fehler: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> Fehler: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The header is in my `.pro` file - so that cannot be the reason. I'm running Qt5 on my Mac - running OS X 10.9 with Xcode installed.

Maybe someone has an idea...

Comment: That's not all the errors - these must be preceded by error messages which list the actual not found symbols.

Comment: I noticed that qmake sometimes doesn't see that it should run `moc` against some class that you just added `Q_OBJECT` to. The `make` sees the file modification and recompiles the file, but `qmake` doesn't see it and it doesn't run `moc` against it. Try to rebuild entire project. It should help.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86\_64" on QtCreator project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973042/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-on-qtcreator-project)

Comment: As a side note, I suggest reading this article first, if you're thinking of inheriting from QThread: http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: Hi Merlin, Im actually working with this article. But thanks.

Comment: An i solved the problem by myself: it was caused by the destructor of my cServer class...

Comment: That is why you need to paste all the errors, not just the ones you think are causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to run `qmake` again on your project and compile again (Qt cannot know that you just added `Q_OBJECT` to a class, so it does not know that it has to run the `moc` compiler on it)...

Comment: After i run qmake again, the error is going away, but after building it after that, the error returns.